# Knockout JS Computed field and aggregate function over array

Tags: knockout.js

I want to create a billing module, in the view I have a table with pre defined no of rows.

When the user enter a product, I populate it with the relevant rate. When he enters a quantity I want to calculate the billed amount for that row i.e Qty * Rate + some other value.
Also a grand total comprising sum of all rows(along with some taxation calculation).

I want to do this using knockout so if the user changes any qty on a row the row amount changes automatically and so does the grand total. Same thing happens when the user add a product or deletes one. But I am confused on how to create the view model.

Please help!!

```
var rows = ko.observableArray([]);
function billRow(rate)
{
    var self = this;
    self.prodQty = ko.observable(0);
    self.prodRate = ko.observable(rate);
    self.making = ko.observable(0);
    self.rowTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.prodQty * self.prodRate) + self.making;
    });
}

function viewmodel() {
    var self = this;
    self.rows = rows;
    self.grossTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.rows().length;i++) {
            total += self.rows()[i].rowTotal();  
        }
        return total;
    });
    self.Vat = ko.computed(function () { return (self.grandTotal * vatRate) / 100; });
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () { return self.grossTotal + self.Vat; });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

The problem is that my table is already rendered with say 10 rows...how am i to bind the rows to this view model

Comment: Please post the what you have so far!

Comment: edited to show the code! I have used foreach binding also just to test added a button on whose click I do javascript:rows.push(new billRow(3150))...but the functionality is not working

Answer (score 1):

The knockout team posted a [good tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) on manipulating collections.

You basically start with a BillingLine object that contains the data you need. 
In that object you have a computed field. That field will catch changes in variables attached to it and recalculate him self based on their values.

Next is the collection holding the BillingLines. each row is an object ... etc

Hope this helps.